# I can't compare dataframe to a string! But I can compare its transpose

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    1: [1, 2],
    2: ['a', 3],
    3: [None, 7]
})

df

   1  2    3
0  1  a  NaN
1  2  3  7.0
```

---

When I compare with a string

```
df == 'a'
```

> ```
> TypeError: Could not compare ['a'] with block values
> ```

However, taking the transpose fixes the problem?!

```
(df.T == 'a').T

       1      2      3
0  False   True  False
1  False  False  False
```

---

What is this error?  Is it something I can fix with how I'm constructing my dataframe?  What is different about comparing to the transpose?

Comment: It basically means you have mixed dtypes (so it cannot hold all values in a single numpy array - it needs to use blocks). When you take the transpose both columns become object so it can do the comparison.

Comment: yeah, i came to the same conclusion... Can't you use `df.astype(str).eq('a')` or `df.select_dtypes(['object']).eq('a')`?

Comment: why I'm still confused is I don't understand why these aren't answers. (-:

Comment: Yea, `df.astype(object) == 'a'` could be one way.

Comment: My knowledge on this block manager is pretty limited so I thought maybe someone might offer a more detailed explanation. :)

Comment: df.info() vs df.T.info() dtypes of columns.

Comment: @piRSquared Apologies if my answer is not comprehensive enough. I am actually looking for some pandas source code to confirm our "hypothesis".

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ you've already got my vote.  Edit away to convince other people to vote! (-:

Comment: Okay, I've found the source code: [pandas/internals.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/793020293ee1e5fa023f45c12943a4ac51cc23d0/pandas/core/internals.py#L1335). This is mostly it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating your data frame, declare `dtype=object`:

```
In [1013]: df = pd.DataFrame({
      ...:     1: [1, 2],
      ...:     2: ['a', 3],
      ...:     3: [None, 7]
      ...: }, dtype=object)

In [1014]: df
Out[1014]: 
   1  2     3
0  1  a  None
1  2  3     7
```

Now, you can compare without transposition:

```
In [1015]: df == 'a'
Out[1015]: 
       1      2      3
0  False   True  False
1  False  False  False
```

My belief is that to begin with, your columns aren't objects (they're coerced wherever possible) but transposition forces the change because of the mixed values.

---

Found this in the source code [`pandas/internals.py`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/793020293ee1e5fa023f45c12943a4ac51cc23d0/pandas/core/internals.py#L1335):

```
if not isinstance(result, np.ndarray):
    # differentiate between an invalid ndarray-ndarray comparison
    # and an invalid type comparison
    ...
    raise TypeError('Could not compare [%s] with block values' %
                    repr(other))
```

If the item being compared does not match the dtype of the array, this error is thrown.

Comment: This question was motivated by me trying to answer one of codeninja's questions and me trying `df == 'Sea'` and running into issues with my test dataframe :-)

Comment: @piRSquared Really! I knew that your suggestion in a comment was inspired by this question but I had no idea this question had been inspired because of that!

Comment: One big circle!